# Can I write a query that will bring me logs with unique identifier (Graylog)?

Tags: uniqueidentifier, graylog

I just started working with graylog and I have some issues.
Can I write a query that will bring me logs with unique identifier?

For examples I have logs with **op_id** and **loan_amt** and I want to get sum of loan_amt from all logs. Here comes the problem : some logs may share same **op_id** and my sum will not be correct because will add plenty times the **loan_amt** from logs with same **op_id**

Can you help me, please?

Comment: So your unique identifiers (op_id) aren't unique?

Comment: They are unique for request, but I can modify loan_amt and it sends the same log message, same op_id, different loan_amt.

Comment: So is `loan_amt` some kind of unique identifier? If not, you should take care that a specific `op_id` is only used once.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you will need to further narrow down your search criteria to filter out duplicate log entries.

You can use the [GrayLog search query language](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/queries.html) to do this.

Try to find fields where duplicate logs differentiate from each other and then create a filter to exclude one from your results.

For example something like this:

`source:hostname.that.logs.loans_amt AND LoggerName:your.logger.that.logs.loan_amt`